# Sorting doubly linked list in java using insertion sort

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I am trying to use insertion sort to sort a doubly linked list. Before sorting, the doubly linked list has the following elements in the following order: 4, 1, 7, 10. The output it supposed to be 1, 4, 7, 10 (basically use the insertionSort method to sort the elements in ascending order).

delete - deletes a node and returns its value

insertAfter(Node n, val v) - inserts a new node with value v after node n

I've tried researching but haven't found anything to solve this.

Can anyone please help me?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DLinkedList {

    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node nextNode;
        private Node prevNode;

        public Node(int v) {
            value = v;
            nextNode = null;
            prevNode = null;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int v) {
            value = v;
        }

        public Node getNextNode() {
            return nextNode;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node n) {
            nextNode = n;
        }

        public Node getPrevNode() {
            return prevNode;
        }

        public void setPrevNode(Node n) {
            prevNode = n;
        }

    }

    // Holds a reference to the head and tail of the list
    private Node headNode;
    private Node tailNode;

    public DLinkedList() {
        headNode = null;
        tailNode = null;
    }

    public void addAtHead(int o) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o); 
        newNode.setNextNode(headNode); 
        if (headNode != null)
            headNode.setPrevNode(newNode);
        headNode = newNode; 
        // special case for empty list
        if (tailNode == null)
            tailNode = newNode;
    }

    public void addAtTail(int o) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o);
        // this means that headNode == null too!
        if(tailNode == null){
            tailNode = newNode;
            headNode = newNode;
        }else{
            newNode.setPrevNode(tailNode);
            tailNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            tailNode = newNode;
        }
    }

    public int deleteAtHead() {
        // list is empty 
        if(headNode == null){
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return -1;
        }
        // singleton: must update tailnode too
        if(headNode == tailNode){
            int res = headNode.getValue();
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return res;
        }

        int res = headNode.getValue();
        headNode = headNode.getNextNode();
        headNode.setPrevNode(null);
        return res;
    }

    public int deleteAtTail() {
        // list is empty 
        if(tailNode == null){
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return -1;
        }
        // singleton: must update tailnode too
        if(headNode == tailNode){
            int res = tailNode.getValue();
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return res;
        }
        int res = tailNode.getValue();
        tailNode = tailNode.getPrevNode();
        tailNode.setNextNode(null);
        return res;
    }

    public int delete(Node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return -1;
        Node next = n.getNextNode();
        Node prev = n.getPrevNode();
        int val = n.getValue();
        if (prev != null)
            prev.setNextNode(next);
        if (next != null)
            next.setPrevNode(prev);
        // deleting at the end
        if (n == tailNode)
            tailNode = prev;
        // deleteing at beginning
        if (n == headNode)
            headNode = next;
        return val;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node n, int val) {
        if (n == null) { // this is the headNode
            addAtHead(val);
            return;
        }
        Node next = n.getNextNode();
        Node newNode = new Node(val);
        newNode.setPrevNode(n);
        newNode.setNextNode(next);
        n.setNextNode(newNode);
        if (next == null) { // insert at tail
            tailNode = newNode;
        } else {
            next.setPrevNode(newNode);
        }
    }

    // computes the size of the list
    public int size() {
        if (headNode == null)
            return 0;
        Node n = headNode;
        int size = 0;
        while (n != null) {
            size++;
            n = n.getNextNode();
        }
        return size;
    }

    // Predicate to check if the linked list is sorted
    public boolean isSorted() {
        if (headNode == null || headNode.nextNode == null)
            return true;
        Node i = headNode.nextNode;
        while (i != null) {
            if (i.getValue() < i.getPrevNode().getValue())
                return false;
            i = i.nextNode;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // toString methods to override printing of object
    public String toString() {
        Node n = headNode;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        while (n != null) {
            buf.append(n.getValue());
            buf.append(" ");
            n = n.getNextNode();
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DLinkedList d = new DLinkedList();
        d.addAtHead(4);
        d.addAtHead(1);
        d.addAtHead(7);
        d.addAtHead(10);
        System.out.println("Before sorting: " + d); // this will call the toString method
        d.insertionSort();
        System.out.println("After sorting: " + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: `current` is never changed

Comment: @Snowy_1803 I've edited the code above to update current to the next node. Now I don't have an infinite loop but the list with 10, 7, 1, 4 becomes 10, 1, 4. Also I have to incorporate the delete and insertAfter methods

Comment: The `addAtHead()` method is missing in your code.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp I have edited to include it

Answer (score 1):

So if you want the list to be sorted why go with sorting at the end ? What I prefer is to insert them in the **sorted way**. So each time an element is inserted, its inserted in a sorted form.
Here is the working code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DLinkedList {

    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node nextNode;
        private Node prevNode;

        public Node(int v) {
            value = v;
            nextNode = null;
            prevNode = null;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int v) {
            value = v;
        }

        public Node getNextNode() {
            return nextNode;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node n) {
            nextNode = n;
        }

        public Node getPrevNode() {
            return prevNode;
        }

        public void setPrevNode(Node n) {
            prevNode = n;
        }
    }

    // Holds a reference to the head and tail of the list
    private Node headNode;
    private Node tailNode;

    public DLinkedList() {
        headNode = null;
        tailNode = null;
    }

    public void addAtHead(int o) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o); 
        newNode.setNextNode(headNode); 
        if (headNode != null)
            headNode.setPrevNode(newNode);
        headNode = newNode; 
        // special case for empty list
        if (tailNode == null)
            tailNode = newNode;
    }

    public void addAtTail(int o) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o);
        // this means that headNode == null too!
        if(tailNode == null){
            tailNode = newNode;
            headNode = newNode;
        }else{
            newNode.setPrevNode(tailNode);
            tailNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            tailNode = newNode;
        }
    }

    public int deleteAtHead() {
        // list is empty 
        if(headNode == null){
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return -1;
        }
        // singleton: must update tailnode too
        if(headNode == tailNode){
            int res = headNode.getValue();
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return res;
        }

        int res = headNode.getValue();
        headNode = headNode.getNextNode();
        headNode.setPrevNode(null);
        return res;
    }

    public int deleteAtTail() {
        // list is empty 
        if(tailNode == null){
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return -1;
        }
        // singleton: must update tailnode too
        if(headNode == tailNode){
            int res = tailNode.getValue();
            headNode = null;
            tailNode = null;
            return res;
        }
        int res = tailNode.getValue();
        tailNode = tailNode.getPrevNode();
        tailNode.setNextNode(null);
        return res;
    }

    public int delete(Node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return -1;
        Node next = n.getNextNode();
        Node prev = n.getPrevNode();
        int val = n.getValue();
        if (prev != null)
            prev.setNextNode(next);
        if (next != null)
            next.setPrevNode(prev);
        // deleting at the end
        if (n == tailNode)
            tailNode = prev;
        // deleteing at beginning
        if (n == headNode)
            headNode = next;
        return val;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node n, int val) {
        if (n == null) { // this is the headNode
            addAtHead(val);
            return;
        }
        Node next = n.getNextNode();
        Node newNode = new Node(val);
        newNode.setPrevNode(n);
        newNode.setNextNode(next);
        n.setNextNode(newNode);
        if (next == null) { // insert at tail
            tailNode = newNode;
        } else {
            next.setPrevNode(newNode);
        }
    }

    // computes the size of the list
    public int size() {
        if (headNode == null)
            return 0;
        Node n = headNode;
        int size = 0;
        while (n != null) {
            size++;
            n = n.getNextNode();
        }
        return size;
    }

    // Predicate to check if the linked list is sorted
    public boolean isSorted() {
        if (headNode == null || headNode.nextNode == null)
            return true;
        Node i = headNode.nextNode;
        while (i != null) {
            if (i.getValue() < i.getPrevNode().getValue())
                return false;
            i = i.nextNode;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // toString methods to override printing of object
    public String toString() 
{
        Node n = headNode;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        while (n != null) {
            buf.append(n.getValue());
            buf.append(" ");
            n = n.getNextNode();
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    // Insert in sorted for so you dont have to sort it after words
    public void sortedInsert(int insertItem){
        Node newNode = new Node(insertItem);
        if(headNode == null){
            headNode = tailNode = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else {
            Node temp = new Node(insertItem);
            Node current = headNode;

            while((current != null) && current.getValue() < insertItem){
                temp = current;
                current = current.getNextNode();
            }
            if(current == headNode){
                addAtHead(insertItem);
                return;
            }
            if (current == null){
                addAtTail(insertItem);
                return;
            }   
                temp.setNextNode(newNode);
                newNode.setNextNode(current);
                current.setPrevNode(newNode);
                newNode.setPrevNode(temp);  
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DLinkedList d = new DLinkedList();
        String beforeSort = "";
        d.sortedInsert(4);

        // you can add the number in the order they are inserted just to show what it will look like unsorted
        beforeSort+=" 4";    
        d.sortedInsert(1);     
        beforeSort+=" 1"; 
        d.sortedInsert(7);
        beforeSort+=" 7"; 
        d.sortedInsert(10);
        beforeSort+=" 10"; 

        System.out.println("Before sorting: " + beforeSort); 
        System.out.println("After sorting: " + d); // this will call the toString method
    }
}
```

Comment: What I think for "doubly linked lists" is to create a new empty doubly linked list, then start traversing the original list and inserting into new list sorted manner. At the end, change "HeadNode" to the "FirstNode" of newly created list.